Infinitely many even pseudo-primes for odd base $a>2$
In the course of investigating certain griup homomorphisms (which I can expand on but which is not directly related to the question, as the question is stand-alone) I was led to considering the existence of even pseudoprimes to a given base, particularly in proving existence and (ideally) that there are infinitely many to any given odd base. In the answer Constructing pseudoprimes to the base 3. a construction is given for constructing infinitely many pseudoprimes to the base $3$. However, this construction only gives odd pseudoprimes (unlike Calvin Lin's assertion in the comments below).
Thus, let $a>2$ be odd. Are there infinitely many even numbers $n$ such that $a^{n-1} \equiv 1 \pmod{n}$? Such numbers are sometimes called even pseudo-primes. To be clear, the case $a=3$ is just asking if the sequence A130433 infinite.

I belive David's answer here gives the answer as Yes.

@CalvinLin No, it doesn’t. Those numbers are all obviously odd.
